# maven and Atmosphere 0.8.4

Tags: maven, atmosphere

i need Atmosphere 0.8.4 in my pom.xml

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.atmosphere</groupId>
        <artifactId>atmosphere-runtime</artifactId>
        <version>0.8.4</version>
        <type>bundle</type>
    </dependency>
```

but i get

```
Could not find artifact org.atmosphere:atmosphere-runtime:bundle:0.8.4 in central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2) -> [Help 1]
```

does anybody know an repository with this dependency?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is right there http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/atmosphere/atmosphere-runtime/0.8.4/
You need to remove type bundle from your dependency declaration.